Symmetry in line and flux integral, or maybe double/ triple integral in general
When I am doing my vector calculus course recently, I realize there are many complex integral could be greatly simplified when considering the symmetry.
I am just wondering if there is a formalization and proof of symmetry method in integration. For example:
If the integrand is an odd function and the path of integration is symmetric about the origin, the integral over the symmetric interval is zero.
In addition, I am having difficulty forming formal symmetry result in 3D(eg. for flux integral).I will really appreciate if any proof and formalization on these topic can be provided. Furthermore, any reference to related material is also appreciated. Thanks!
This is an example of the symmetry in action
This is a continuation of example
I think we can do it without completing the parametrization by simply recognizing(1)the function(F) is an odd function(2)The path is symmetrical.
(1)&(2)==>The line integral=0
What I am interested is if this is valid way to do it(leveraging symmetry)? Can we extend this argument to deal with line integral with symmetry in general?  Thanks!

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Your question is way too broad. The example of $F(x,y)=(y^3,x^3)$ integrated around the unit circle is perfect for you to practice with a reasoning that uses only the symmetry.  Awaiting your attempts.

Thanks for the reply. The thing is I am having difficulty being confident about the validity of my symmetry argument(i.e I am not sure whether my intuition for the symmetry argument is justified.) I have to admit this is a very broad question, but I think making generalization(and justifying them) enable time saving and simplicity for future problem.Cheers.

I have not seen a complete symmetry argument in your post that could be evaluated. Besides: it is wrong (see my answer). My point is that one cannot learn that stuff from an abstract generalization. Practice examples and gain experience.

That post is I think useful but badly written. You could do future students a favour by putting the images into mathJax format.


The "symmetry argument" that $\mathbf F(-x,-y)=-\mathbf F(x,y)$ leads to
$$\tag1
\oint_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=0
$$
($C$ being the unit circle) is wrong:
Consider the example
$$\tag2
\mathbf F(x,y)={-x^2y\choose xy^2}\,.
$$
By Green's theorem
$$\tag3
\oint_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{r}=\oint_C F^x\,dx+F^y\,dy=\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial F^y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F^x}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy\,
$$
where $D$ is the unit disk.
The integrand in the last integral is
$$\tag4
\frac{\partial F^y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F^x}{\partial y}=y^2+x^2=r^2
$$
so that we can use polar coordinates and get an integral of $2\pi\int_0^1 r^3\,dr=\pi/2\,.$

In your case
$$\tag5
\mathbf F(x,y)={y^3\choose x^3}
$$
that integrand becomes
$$\tag6
\frac{\partial F^y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F^x}{\partial y}=3y^2-3x^2\,.
$$
What symmetry can you think of that makes the two integrals
$$\tag7
\iint_Dy^2\,dx\,dy\quad\text{ and }\quad\iint_Dx^2\,dx\,dy
$$
equal and therefore leads to a zero total integral?



@chou sounds right! What I wanted to demonstrate is that symmetry arguments cannot really be taught like an algorithm. You need to dig a bit to find the spot where to get over the hurdle. That argument I just found yesterday on the basis of the concrete example.

Glad that you actually see my comment, thanks for exploring in another perspective(Green's theorem namely).If no strict algorithm can be found then I guess we have to stick with our intuition sometimes. Thanks!
